# Deployment script taking too long

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, static-content-deploy, slow-response

When I am creating new module I ran following commands for full deployment:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But it took so much time, 30 minutes approx

How can I make it more faster?

Comment: what is your server configuration and magento version?

Comment: Magento 2.2.7, I am using xamp, its on local environment

Comment: On which mode you are working right now? Please check and do let me know  `magento deploy:mode:show`

Comment: its on default mode

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most time taken process in your listed commands are:

1. Upgrade: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. Di Compile: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

By doing 2 basic tasks you will speedup your these commands.

**First:** Change mode to production (if it is default or development)

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

**Note: If your project is at development phase, then you need development mode for error reporting and other stuff**

**Second:** integrate **Eleanorsoft** module in your project.
[Download Eleanorsoft](https://github.com/Eleanorsoft/magento-dicompile)

- Copy Eleanorsoft folder to `app/code/`.
- Run `setup:upgrade.`
- Run `setup:di:compile`.
- After compilation, you should see a folder `var/di_cache/` with 4 (or more) files. This is the actual cache. From now your compilation process will use these cached lists instead of scanning the whole filesystem.

I personally integrated this module just now and noticed, di compile tool **19 mins** at first, but after integrating this module it completed in just **8 mins**

Reference of eleanorsoft: https://www.eleanorsoft.com/speed-up-magento-2-di-compilation-setupdicompile/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will try this solution. Will let you know if it worked for me

Comment: It worked. Much optimized now